# Decode base64 encrypted LogResult of "AWS Lambda invoke" in Windows PowerShell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am using `AWS Lambda Invoke` to test my lambda functions from Powershell. Unfortunately I can't manage to get a usefull log result. If I decode the result like this there are not line breaks seperating the log-lines:

```
$response = aws lambda invoke --function-name my-lambda-function --invocation-type RequestResponse --log-type Tail --payload file://sample-event.json outfile.txt | ConvertFrom-Json
$DecodedText = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($response.LogResult))
$DecodedText
```

Any idea what I can do to have the logs nice and readabel line after line?

Comment: Can you supply an example of the base64 string present in `$response.LogResult`?

Comment: Here's how you do it on UNIX w/ AWS CLI: `aws lambda invoke --function-name XYZ --invocation-type RequestResponse --log-type Tail - | grep "LogResult"| awk -F'"' '{print $4}' | base64 --decode`

Comment: @pjb Great comment and this works for me. You should make this an official answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: @Jberg did this work for you on Windows PowerShell? I think it only works on UNIX but I was specifically looking for a solution on Windows PowerShell.

Comment: Oh no, I'm on Mac using bash. I missed the PowerShell part, but that does work well in bash which Windows 10 now supports. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: @pjb thank you for help. Please post as answer; please describe cryptic -F'"' ' or simplify if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Windows, but I head that Bash is available under Linux subsystem also. Inside of every lambda directory I have file `invoke.sh` with code like this:

```
NAME=getLineUpMap
OUT=/tmp/awsLambdaOut.txt

AWS_PROFILE=gms-ai \
aws lambda invoke \
--function-name $NAME \
--payload '{"specs": ["RPM", "Energy"], "numberOfModels": 3}' --log-type Tail \
$OUT |
grep "LogResult" |
awk --field-separator '"' '{print $4}' |
base64 --decode |
grep --color "$NAME\|$" --text

cat $OUT | python3 -m json.tool
```

Example of output:

```
START RequestId: cc22c01a-fdd0-4944-9d78-ef298fb6ef72 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: cc22c01a-fdd0-4944-9d78-ef298fb6ef72
REPORT RequestId: cc22c01a-fdd0-4944-9d78-ef298fb6ef72  Duration: 75.75 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 63 MB  
{
    "Models": [
        {
            "Specs": {
                "Energy": "A++",
                "RPM": "1200"
            },
            "Percent": 14
        },
        {
            "Specs": {
                "Energy": "A++",
                "RPM": "1000"
            },
            "Percent": 12
        },
        {
            "Specs": {
                "Energy": "A+++",
                "RPM": "1200"
            },
            "Percent": 12
        }
    ],
    "Rows": {
        "1000": 31,
        "1200": 38,
        "1400": 29
    }
}
```